# Selenium c# find element select element exception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm fairly new to c# and writing a simple selenium code which will go onto www.asos.com. I then click on the country on the right hand side by finding the xpath. When I click on the country I want to change the country to 'india' and the currency to 'USD', and then select my preference.

I'm getting exception for  `driver.FindElement`, `SelectElement`, `SelectByValue` previously when using java I wasn't getting these exceptions.

Exception I see for `driver` = The name driver doesn't exist in the current context

`SelectElement` = the type or namespace name 'SelectElement' could not be found

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"Path to my chrome driver defined here");
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.asos.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="chrome - header"]/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/div/button')]")).Click();

            var country = driver.FindElement(By.Id("country"));
            var select_country = new SelectElement(country);
            select_country = SelectByValue("India");

            var currency = driver.FindElement(By.Id("currency"));
            var select_currency = new SelectElement(currency);
            select_currency = SelectByValue("$ USD");

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="chrome - header"]/header/div[5]/div[2]/div/section/form/div[3]/button")).Click();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value of the option in the html. Also call the select on the select element. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(@"Path to my chrome driver defined here");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.asos.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='chrome - header']/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/div/button')]")).Click();

            var country = driver.FindElement(By.Id("country"));
            var select_country = new SelectElement(country);
            select_country.SelectByValue("IN");

            var currency = driver.FindElement(By.Id("currency"));
            var select_currency = new SelectElement(currency);
            select_currency.SelectByValue("2");

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='chrome - header']/header/div[5]/div[2]/div/section/form/div[3]/button")).Click();

        }
}
```

You may also want to throw in some waits to give the page time to load.

Comment: Thanks, but driver.FindElement, SelectElement and SelectByValue are all throwing an exception

Comment: @J.dockster Please look at my select_country.Select addition. Can you post the exception you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

> driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="chrome - header"]/header/div[5]/div[2]/div/section/form/div[3]/button")).Click();

The erro in quotation marks, try:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='chrome - header']/header/div[5]/div[2]/div/section/form/div[3]/button")).Click();
```

Comment: Same for all xpath

Comment: Perfect that's fixed that exception